# How to implement a two-finger PanGesture instance in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a multi-touch scenario for a PanGestureRecognizer instance in Xamarin.Forms, but don't know the best approach.

I am very new to the Xamarin ecosystem and C# as a whole, so while I have successfully implemented a PanGestureRecognizer instance for one finger, as is the default setup, I am not sure where to go to get a view to only pan when two fingers are dragging at the same time.

I am just trying to get a view I have created to only pan across the screen when dragged with two fingers. I cannot use any 3rd party licenses.

Comment: Can you add some of your code to your question so we can see what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the TouchPoints property of PanGestureRecognizer.

Check out the link:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.pangesturerecognizer.touchpoints?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_PanGestureRecognizer_TouchPoints

Code :-

```
PanGestureRecognizer pgr = new PanGestureRecognizer();
pgr.TouchPoints = 2;
```

Same can be set in Xaml as well.

Answer (score 1):

To make a user interface element moveable with the pan gesture, create a [PanGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan) instance, handle the PanUpdated event, and add the new gesture recognizer to the GestureRecognizers collection on the user interface element. The following code example shows a PanGestureRecognizer attached to an **Image** element:

```
var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
panGesture.TouchPoints = 2; //Set finger to 2 
panGesture.PanUpdated += (s, e) => {
  // Handle the pan
};
image.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
```

This can also be achieved in **XAML**, as shown in the following code example:

```
<Image Source="MonoMonkey.jpg">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated" TouchPoints="2"/>
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

The code for the `OnPanUpdated` event handler is then added to the code-behind file:

```
void OnPanUpdated (object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
  // Handle the pan
}
```